# Cutting a thread deeper in metal.

Tags: screws

I am trying to put together a TV Stand with 3 legs- 2 of which are supported via  18 inch metal rods within plastic tubes, screwed into the base. The depth of the hole in one of these is too shallow so the rod is easily loosened- rendering it useless. How can I increase the depth of the threads in this (aluminium) hole; or increase the rigidity of the rod?

Comment: Your question is unclear - screws don't loosen just because they're short.  Please post a picture and identify the exact area in question.

Comment: Deoending how loose it is you might try wrapping it in Teflon tape.

Comment: @carl they may loosen because they are bottoming or they have run out of thread.

Comment: We need to know more details. Can we assume that this is not any type of sheet metal screw, but rather a machine screw thread such as 6-32, 8-32, 10-24, 10-32, 1/4-20, or 1/4-28? The first number is the diameter, and the second number is the number of threads per inch. A photo of the screw and hole would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

If the hole is there but not threaded you can cut the thread deeper with a [tap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_and_die). You need to be sure of the size, which is easier to measure on the external thread of the mating part. Often the hole is also too loose though.

Comment: I'd recommend buying a thread gauge to be sure. They're cheap.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I agree, though taking a part to a decent hardware shop works too. So does gently winding a candidate tap into the hole, especially if you can be sure it's metric.

Comment: Hi again. I don't know the tech term for it but the suggestion that the screw hole is too shallow I made because the threads on the 2 parts don't bind except for the 1st or 2nd rotation of the rod; the rod then dislodges from the threads and I'm back to square one. (There is a superfluous amount of thread on the rod, by the way). I think the tap or the teflon tape could work. Thanks guys!

Comment: It sounds more like the thread is badly cut than the hole is too shallow.  Running a tap down it may or may not help.

Comment: The hole may need to be drilled deeper with the correct size tap drill.

Answer (score 1):

If the hole is not deep enough it will need to be drilled deeper, first the correct tap size would be needed once the correct size/ pitch of the tap is identified then the correct drill size can be found online. Don't use a clearance drill size or you will wipe out the threads use the tap drill size to make the hole deeper, once the hole is deep enough a "bottoming"  tap can be used or a standard tap (a bottoming tap has a shorter tip so the hole dosent need to be as deep if there is not enough material to drill into.

Comment: Bottoming tap, exactly! I usually make mine by grinding off the tip of the tap so that only a small portion of the taper is left.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the hole is badly threaded.  You have several options:

1. There are thread repair kits like the Helicoil in which you install a wire effectively creating new threads.
2. There are repair kits in which you drill out the hold and tap into it a plug which bites into the sides of the hole and has a threaded center.
3. You could drill out the hole, thread it for the larger size and get a new rod threaded for that.
4. You could epoxy the original rod into the existing hole.  Clean both sides first.  (Kind of permanent).
5. You could try and fill the hole in with something like JB Weld and redrill and retap (possibly weak).